# app launcher icon changed to default icon on Oreo

Tags: android, launcher, android-8.0-oreo

I have created an Android app with its own launcher icon. It worked well with Nougat. But with Oreo, my icon is replaced by the default Android icon.
I have defined `ic_launcher.png` and `ic_launcher_round.png` in the mipmap resources for several densities.

My manifest contains the following line:

```
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

What should I do to make my own icon appear on Oreo ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For API 26+ default Android application template defines another icon resource folder

`mipmap-anydpi-v26`

That folder (usually) contains two `xml` files `ic_launcher` and `ic_launcher_round` that match icon resources declared in manifest for API 26+

Content of those files looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

In order to have your icon you also need to change all drawables (in all density buckets) listed there - namely `ic_launcher_background` and `ic_launcher_foreground`

Or you can just delete that folder, in which case android will fallback to using your png icons, but they will not appear as-is and will be commonly drawn on top of white background.

You can read more at: [Adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive)

Comment: Thanks Dalija. I did not notice this mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder. I have just removed it, and it works fine now on Oreo. I will check later what I can really do with this "adaptive-icon".

Comment: @VadimKotov I added link for Adaptive icons. Default template and its content in Android Studio is not documented AFAIK.

Answer (score 10):

Best solution is delete mipmap-anydpi-v26  folder then app will take default icon. In android studio Project mode go to this package

> res/mipmap-anydpi-v26

delete it and rebuild and Run Project.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
check res/mipmap-anydpi-v26 folder, then you will see ic_launcher.xml and ic_launcher_round.xml files
edit these xml files to point to the actual png file you want to use:

If such png file is not available inside the drawable folder, add it.

That solves the issue.